# How to create arrays based on values from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects. All objects have the same properties. I'm trying to find a way to create new arrays for each of the common id's.
This is my array:
`

```
var array = 
  [
    {
      id: "BG",
      qty: 100
    }, 
    {
      id: "BG",
      qty: 35
    }, 
    {
      id: "JP",
      qty: 75
    },
    {
      id: "JP",
      qty: 50
    }
 ];
```

`

I wan it to create arrays based on the id property. Based on the above array, I'm expecting 2 arrays for BG and JP.

I tried this but it creates an array with just the 2 id's
`const uniqueId = [...new Set(array.map(array => array.id))];`

What I want my result to be is:

```
[{
  id: "BG",
  qty: 100
}, 
{
  id: "BG",
  qty: 35
}]
[{
      id: "JP",
      qty: 75
    },
    {
      id: "JP",
      qty: 50
    }
 ]
```

Comment: `array.reduce()` is your friend

Comment: [A similar question was asked today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74447457/18244921)

Comment: Please edit your expected output so it's valid JavaScript. It's kind of hard to figure out exactly what you want.

Comment: `array.reduce((obj, cur) => (obj[cur.id] = [...(obj[cur.id] || []), cur], obj), {})`?

Comment: If you can use lodash, [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) would do what you want here. `_.groupBy(array, 'id')` returns `{ BG: [{ id: 'BG', qty: 100 }, { id: 'BG', qty: 35 }], JP: [{ id: 'JP', qty: 75 }, { id: 'JP', qty: 50 }] }`

Comment: so now how would I be able to sum the values of the quantities for the new arrays? so im expecting to add up all the BG and all the JP qty properties

Answer (score 1):

This can help you

```
var results = array.reduce(function(results, org) {
    (results[org.id] = results[org.id] || []).push(org);
    return results;
}, {})
```

I took it of:
[Group by Object ID's in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281405/group-by-object-ids-in-javascript)

Comment: Can use `Object.values(results)` at the end if OP wants multiple arrays instead of single object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).