# how to sum property values of arrays created by reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code **:**

```
var array = 
  [
    {
      id: "BG",
      qty: 100
    }, 
    {
      id: "BG",
      qty: 35
    }, 
    {
      id: "JP",
      qty: 75
    },
    {
      id: "JP",
      qty: 50
    }
 ];


var result = array.reduce((obj, cur) => (obj[cur.id] = [...(obj[cur.id] || []), cur], obj), {})
console.log(result);
```

What I would like to do is group the array into sub arrays based on the ID's which the `array.reduce` does. But now I want to sum the total of the qty.

So I'm expecting values the total qty for BG to be = 35 and the total qty for JP to be 125, and then I want to be able to run math conditions on those numbers

Comment: Could you not have used the information you received from the [question you asked an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452095/how-to-create-arrays-based-on-values-from-another-array) to decipher the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create arrays based on values from another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452095/how-to-create-arrays-based-on-values-from-another-array)

Answer (score 1):

It really have been asked before, but by the time I'd search for it I could also write it. It's not that long.

```js
var array = [{
    id: "BG",
    qty: 100
  },
  {
    id: "BG",
    qty: 35
  },
  {
    id: "JP",
    qty: 75
  },
  {
    id: "JP",
    qty: 50
  }
];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.id] = agg[item.id] || {
    id: item.id,
    qty: 0
  }
  agg[item.id].qty += item.qty;
  return agg;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```